# Get Jetty's initParameter or attributes in Spring

Tags: java, spring, embedded-jetty

Here is what I do now:

In a Main class that starts several embedded Jetty servers:

```
System.setProperty("someParameter", "someValue");
WebAppContext appContext = new WebAppContext();
webAppContext.setContextPath("/");
webAppcontext.setDescriptor("src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml");

Server server = new Server(8080);
server.setHandler(webAppContext);
server.start()
```

And in my `application-config.xml` from spring I retrieve the value like this:

```
<bean id="testController" class="test.TestController">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="#{ systemProperties['someParameter'] }" />
</bean>
```

This works, but, since I start a few servers in a loop (with different ports, 8080 +i), the systemProperty gets overwritten, so I would like to set the system property as an attribute to the webAppContext like this:

```
appContext.setAttribute("someParameter", "someValue");
```

or like this

```
appContext.setInitParameter("someParameter", "someValue");
```

But I can't seem to find a way to retrieve these parameters/attributes in the Spring context.

Is there anyway to retrieve these parameters/attributes in the Spring context?

Comment: Don't use an expression, simply use `${someParameter}` and add a `<context:property-placeholder />`. This will register the needed infrastructure and allows to specify the property in the servletcontext, system properties or system environment.

Answer (score 0):

Solved (Thanks to @M. Deinum ):

After adding

```
<context:property-placeholder />
```

to the application-config.xml, the value set with

```
appContext.setInitParameter("someParameter", "someValue")
```

can be retrieved using

```
<constructor-arg index="0" value="${someParameter}" />
```